# Getting the row's occurence of max value by column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "a": [0.02, 0.04, -0.1,-0.02],
  "b": [0.04, -0.1, -0.02,0.01],
  "c": [0.01, 0.3, 0.02,0.02],
  "d": [-0.07,0.02,-0.01,0.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'd like to get the following table:

| dataset | no of being max a column |
| --- | --- |
| c | 3 |
| b | 1 |
| a | 0 |
| d | 0 |

C would be 3 as in the 4 given column (months) there were 3 months when C had the highest performance.

Edit:
Would the structure of the dataframe into table-like format change the way how I can get the correct output?
For instance if the way I create my dataframe would be something like this:

```
a = [0.02, 0.04, -0.1,-0.02]
b = [0.04, -0.1, -0.02,0.01]
c = [0.01, 0.3, 0.02,0.02]
d = [-0.07,0.02,-0.01,0.0]

total = [a,b,c,d]
total2 = ['a','b','c','d']

df_final = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(range(4)), index=['a','b','c','d'])
i=0

for l in total2:
    df_final.loc[l] = total[i]
    i += 1
    
print(df_final)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)/[`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) & [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) :

```
out = (df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).sum()
       .sort_values(ascending=False).rename_axis("dataset")
       .reset_index(name="no of being max a column"))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  dataset  no of being max a column
0       c                         3
1       b                         1
2       a                         0
3       d                         0
```

Comment: Would this solution be also applicable if my dataframe is created the way how I just updated the question? I am getting the actual months as datasets now, not the letters a-d

Comment: Yes, you just need to replace every `df` with `df_final.T` in the first line of my code.

Comment: Or the whole line with `(df_final.eq(df_final.max(axis=0), axis=1).sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, which uses `numpy` to compare columns:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    zip(df.columns,
        [(df.values <= df[x].values.reshape(-1,1)).all(1).sum()
         for x in df.columns]),
    columns = ['dataset', 'no of being max a column'])
```

Output:

```
  dataset  no of being max a column
0       a                         0
1       b                         1
2       c                         3
3       d                         0
```

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat longer solution with `idxmax`, `groupby`/`count`, and `join`

```py
countmax = ( 
   # initialize dataframe with zeros
   pd.DataFrame({'countmax':[0]*4}, 
                index=pd.Index(df.columns, name='dataset')) 
      .join(
            # for each row compute which column holds maximum value
            df.idxmax(axis='columns')
              # group by itself  
              .groupby(df.idxmax(axis='columns'))
              # count number of occurrences of each index
              .count()
              # the name for join should not be empty
              .rename('count'))
      # the value in each row is either zero or count
      .max(axis='columns')
      # convert from pandas default floats back to integers
      .astype(int)
      # sort descending
      .sort_values(ascending=False)
      # rename 
      .rename('no of being max a column')
)
```

would return a series object

```
dataset
c    3
b    1
a    0
d    0
Name: no of being max a column, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `idxmax()`

```
    (df.idxmax(axis=1)
.value_counts()
.reindex(df.columns,fill_value=0)
.sort_values(ascending=False)
.reset_index()
.set_axis(['dataset','no of being a max column'],axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  dataset  no of being a max column
0       c                         3
1       b                         1
2       a                         0
3       d                         0
```